# Odoo 10 - Sending emails with sale orders or invoices

Tags: odoo-10

I have installed and configured odoo (v10) on my own server but I can't send email an email from sale order or invoice.
My mail configuration is good as I'm able to send out password resets via mail or send an email from the configuration > mail.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First you need to set outgoing mail server. After setting that need to set that outgoing server to your email template. In your case you have to set your outgoing server to "Invoice - Send by Email" template (for sending sale order) . In that template there is a tab name "Advance Setting" . From there in "Outgoing Mail Server" . Here set your outgoing mail server. After this you can able to send emails.

Answer (score 1):

Have you setup an outgoing email server yet?

- Activate Developer Mode.
- Navigate To Settings > Technical > Email > Outgoing Email Servers.
- Edit the existing one or create your own and test the connection.

It's easy to use a simple Gmail address with smtp.gmail.com to start out with as the smtp server. Quick way to test.

[Menu Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u26kD.png)

[Outgoing Email Server Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CTk4.png)